# A kotlin coroutine's parent context is different from its parent's context

Tags: kotlin

I am reading this tutorial: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/coroutines-first-things-first-e6187bf3bb21
It seems that a coroutine's parent context is different from ts parent's context. Let's look at this code:

```
     val scope = CoroutineScope.launch (Job() + Dispatcher.Main + coroutineExceptionHandler){
                 // `mother`
                               
                }
     val job = scope.launch(Dispatcher.IO) { // `new`}
```

Now the parent context of `new` is:  Dispatcher.IO, Job(), coroutineExceptionHandler, "coroutine"

What's the point of making `new`'s parent context different from `mother`?

Comment: This code doesn’t make sense. `scope` is actually a job because you called `launch` on a CoroutineScope and assign the returned Job to `scope`. So you would not be able to call launch on `scope` like you have done on the last line.

Comment: This code does not even compile, but anyway: why do you assume these contexts should be the same? Most coroutine builder and scoping functions modify the context. This is exactly how they should behave.

Comment: I am learning coroutines and the theory is confusing. For example, here's the text from the link I gave above `However, the resulting parent CoroutineContext of a coroutine can be different from the CoroutineContext of the parent since it’s calculated based on this formula:`  To me it reads like this: `Your father can be different from your father.`. It doesn't make sense. Why do you calculate the resulting parent coroutineContext?

Comment: This part is confusing to me as well. Note this is not an official documentation. This all may seem complicated, but is in fact pretty simple. Coroutine context is a map-like data structure attached to a coroutine, similarly as thread-locals are attached to threads. When going deeper into the coroutine execution tree, context is automatically inherited, but it may be modified by adding, removing or replacing its items.

Comment: @ntos do you understand the meaning after 2 years? it's still confusing to me :)))